# Custom Time Slots

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Is it possible to set the time slots to 90 minutes and put a 15 minute "break" in between?
And also display the time axis (e.g. 08:00 - 09:30) like in the image below?

Thank you for your help!

[image: Example image]

Comment: Not without making a completely custom view, no. And even then, I suspect it would probably be quite difficult. Certainly, creating custom views is not a simple or short task, anyhow. IMO you would be better to create 15-minute time slots and then restrict what people can choose - first by setting the "break" slots as Background Events, or perhaps by using multiple "Business Hours" settings to show available times.

Comment: And/or you could also use the other date clicking/selecting/dragging "constraint" and "allow" hooks to control where users can place their events. Have a good look through all the options in the documentation. With a working knowledge of the available options and a bit of imagination you should be able to come up with something which will meet your needs pretty closely, if not perfectly. https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc